Navegadores Web en Terminal Server de Windows Server
¿Es posible usar los navegadores actuales más comunes como Chrome, Firefox o Edge en varias sesiones de Terminal Server o Escritorio Remoto en los Windows Server 2016/2019?, ya que al hacerle clic en otra sesión, si ya está abierto en otra, no responde.
